# How to tell if PDO found a match to my UPDATE query, and updated or not?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
UPDATE users SET 'name'='john' WHERE users.ID = 54;
```

actually all this question is about `pdo::rowCount`, as I need to know that a match to the query was:
1. found, but need not to update (matching values)
2. found, and updated
3. not found at all, (not updated)

I am looking for a way to tell in PHP one of those three options

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is.

Comment: The PHP manual about `PDO::rowCount` says `PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement.` and one comment says `When updating a Mysql table with identical values nothing's really affected so rowCount will return 0. As Mr. Perl below noted this is not always preferred behaviour and you can change it yourself since PHP 5.3.`, so to me it sounds like it only returns the row count of found and updated rows.

Comment: And that is the problem, how do you tell if this 3 or 1 ?

Comment: Well, the method is 2. If you want the one of the other you need to make a SELECT statement and count the rows.

Comment: I'm not really sure for what you need that.

Comment: Just do a select query before the update with the same ID if it returns ant row then there is no need to update And if want just update it with the id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented under [UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html):

> [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html) returns the number of rows that were actually changed. The [`mysql_info()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-info.html) C API function returns the number of rows that were matched and updated and the number of warnings that occurred during the [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html).

In particular, after an `UPDATE` query [`mysql_info()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-info.html) returns [`ER_UPDATE_INFO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_update_info).  [The MySQL Command-Line Tool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) displays such information immediately after a command is issued.  For example:

```
mysql> UPDATE users SET name='john' WHERE ID=54;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

[MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) provides direct access to this function, through [`mysqli::$info`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php).  Even the [Original MySQL API](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) provided access thereto, through its own [`mysql_info()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-info.php) function.

Unfortunately, PDO provides no access to this function—a search of the codebase confirms that it never calls [`mysql_info()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-info.html).

Alternatively, clients can set the [`CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-real-connect.html) connection flag—then [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html) will return the number of rows that matched rather than the number that were changed.  PDO does provide access to set this connection flag, via the [`PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo.constants.mysql-attr-found-rows) driver-specific attribute.

However this connection flag is of little use to you, as instead of being unable to differentiate between "*not found at all*" and "*found but no update*", it will leave you unable to differentiate between "*found but no update*" and "*found and updated*".

Thus, as others have already suggested, your only option in this case would be to perform a separate `SELECT` query to differentiate between the possible conditions.  In order to avoid race hazards, you should be careful to perform the `SELECT` within the same transaction and to use a [locking read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) if reading before updating.